# Populate object list with datarow fields

Tags: c#, asynchronous, datatable

I was wondering about what is the fastest and best practice way to populate an object list with DataTable data

currently I'm using this method:

The object:

```
public class Car
{
    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public Car(DataRow row)
    {
        if (row != null)
        {
            this.CarId = Convert.ToInt32(row["car_id"]);
            this.CarName = row["car_name"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

the Conversion:

```
public List<Car> GetCars(DataTable carTable)
    {
        return carTable.Select().SelectAsync(c => new Car(c)).ToList();
    }
```

and the async extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<S> SelectAsync<T, S>(this IEnumerable<T> query, Func<T, S> expression)
    {
        TaskFactory<S> tasks = new TaskFactory<S>();
        foreach (var item in query)
        {
            yield return tasks.StartNew(() => expression(item)).Result;
        }
    }
```

I'm aware that I could use "AsParallel", but from tests I've made, this method is slightly faster

but still, can someone help me find a faster way to do it?
is there a design pattern for that?

Thank you